# Access Nested Objects in JSTL on to JSP Page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, nested, jstl

**I am having two classes:**

lets say

```
class ABC{

private String a,b;

public void setA(String a){
this.a = a;
}

public void setB(String b){
this.b = b;
}

public String getA(){
return this.a;
}

public String getB(){
return this.b ;
}

}



class XYZ{

private ABC abc;

public void setABC(ABC abc){
this.abc = abc;
}

public ABC getABC(){
return this.abc;
}

}
```

Class XYZ having class ABC property.

I want to access class ABC property's a or b in one of the JSP page with the help of JSTL
in this fashion

```
${XYZ.ABC.A}
```

Comment: What's the problem with that? Did you try anything?

Comment: no error but no output as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reference beans in the JSP needs to put the object into request.

```
request.setAttribute("xyz", xyz);
```

then access it via `${xyz.abc.a}` in the JSP.

Comment: please refer this link , this guy is having the same issue, this may exaplain u the thing http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?387623-Cant-access-nested-properties-via-jstl-in-a-jsp-page

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with JSTL tags.Try this
${XYZ object name.abc.a}

Comment: i tried but no output i can access xyz properties but when i am trying to access abc properites like ${xyz.ABC.A} no output

Comment: please refer this link , this guy is having the same issue, this may exaplin u the thing http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?387623-Cant-access-nested-properties-via-jstl-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: in that issue the semicolon in the expression

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public void setABC(ABC abc){
this.abc = abc;
}

public ABC getABC(){
return this.abc;
}
```

use

```
public void setAbc(ABC abc){
this.abc = abc;
}

public ABC getAbc(){
return this.abc;
}
```

Retrive the information by using this JSTL syntax
    ${XYZ.abc.a}

Comment: ok i will try .... but i think the thing is some thing else..i mean i need to access the thing in other fashion not like the way i am doing...

Comment: please refer this link , this guy is having the same issue,  this may exaplin u the thing http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?387623-Cant-access-nested-properties-via-jstl-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: Please go step by step... check whether the Object of XYZ is null or not. If not null, then try with ${object of XYZ.abc}. Whether this value is null or not. If it is not null, then retrieve the value of "a".

Answer (score 0):

I see this question cropping up a lot, so I've added definitive syntax, and an example at the end.

The first problem is, as far as I'm aware, you can't easily add multiple models to a form.

```
modelAttribute="productDTO" //is okay

modelAttribute="productDTO, vatDTO" //doesn't work
```

Unlike other posters have said, simply trying

```
${A.B.C}
```

will also not work if B is an object that would require its own model. The simple solution, rather than creating a special DTO just to house all the extra objects is to add an extra "getter" method to your "productDTO" class, one that simply returns a String code, or other simple type:

```
   public class ProductDTO implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974170234812308892L;
       VatCode vatCode; //an object

       public String getVatCodeAsString() {
           return vatCode.getVATCode(); //useful if it's a code or something flat
       }

       public VatCode getVatCode() {
           return vatCode(); //the JSP won't know what this model is
       }
```

Then you can access this method in your jsp page:

```
value="${productDTO.vatCodeAsString}
```

I use this and I can vouch that it works.

---

If you are, however, needing to access complicated objects, the syntax works like this:

In your controller :

```
 ProductAdminWebDTO productAdminWebDTO = new ProductAdminWebDTO();
 productAdminWebDTO.setProductDTO(productService.getProductByID(prodNo)); 
 modelAndView.addObject("productAdminWebDTO", productAdminWebDTO);
```

Where ProductAdminWebDTO contains:

```
private ProductDTO productDTO;
```

Where ProductDTO contains:

```
 private String productName; //(make sure to add correct getter, setters)
```

In your JSP:

```
 <form:form method="post" id="viewForm"
               action="GET" modelAttribute="productAdminWebDTO">

<form:input path="productDTO" id="productDTO" type="text" value="${productAdminWebDTO.productDTO.productName}"/>
```

Notice, the top level element is "productAdminWebDTO", but in the path, you only add the element that corresponds to the contained variable. But the full path, (as pointed out by other posters), in the value.